# Generalised form of $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ [SOLVED]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So for groups, we know that the cardinality of the product of two subgroups is given by the formula $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$, where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of the group $G$. However, after scouring the internet I cannot seem to find a formula for the cardinality of the product of three or more subgroups.

**Failed attempt:**

I conjectured that the cardinality of the product of three subgroups is given by the formula

$$|XYZ|=\frac{|X||Y||Z||X \cap Y \cap Z|}{|X \cap Y||X \cap Z||Y \cap Z|},$$
where $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are subgroups of the group $G$.

Similarly, the cardinality of the product of four subgroups should be given by the formula
$$|WXYZ|=\frac{|W||X||Y||Z| |W \cap X \cap Y| |W \cap X \cap Z| |W \cap Y \cap Z| |X \cap Y \cap Z|}{|W \cap X| |W \cap Y| |W \cap Z| |X \cap Y||X \cap Z||Y \cap Z||W\cap X \cap Y \cap Z|},$$
where $W$, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are subgroups of the group $G$.

I conjectured these formulas because the formula for the cardinality of two subgroups seems to have a similar structure to the principle of inclusion and exclusion $(|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|)$ and also the formula $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\gcd(x,y)}$. Therefore, the formula for the cardinality of the product of three subgroups should somewhat follow the pattern for $|A \cup B \cup C|$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y,z)$ in my humble opinion. (although if it doesn’t, I wouldn’t be very surprised either because my argument isn’t very rigorous).

I have checked that the formula

$$|XYZ|=\frac{|X||Y||Z||X \cap Y \cap Z|}{|X \cap Y||X \cap Z||Y \cap Z|},$$

holds for the example $G=\mathbb{Z}/120\mathbb{Z}$, $X= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $Y= \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $Z=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Also, the formula holds when you let the subgroup $Z$ be the subgroup $X\cap Y$.

Sadly, reality is often times disappointing because I managed to find a counter example to the above formula. By letting the group $G$ be $S_3$, $X=\{(1),(12)\}$, $Y=\{(1),(13)\}$ and $Z=\{(1),(123),(132)\}$. In this example, it isn’t hard to see that the right hand side of the formula would give us $\frac{2\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 1}{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}=12$. However, on the left hand side of the formula, $XYZ$ is a subset of $S_3$ and hence its cardinality has to be less than the order of $S_3$ which is 6, a contradiction.

Since my formula failed to hold water, the only natural question to have is what is the formula for $|XYZ|$? And perhaps what is the formula of the cardinality of the product of $n$ many subgroups of $G$ be? Will somebody who is rather experienced in this field be able to satisfy my curiousity?

**Current progress:**

1. We can derive a formula for $|XYZ|$ if we were to assume that one of the subgroups is normal
   If we were to assume that one of these three subgroups are normal, then either $(XY)$ or $(YZ)$ is a subgroup of $G$. In the case that $(XY)$ is the subgroup, we can deduce that
   $$|XYZ|=\frac{|XY|\cdot|Z|}{|XY\cap Z|}=\frac{|X|\cdot |Y|}{|X\cap Y|}\cdot \frac{|Z|}{|XY\cap Z|}=\frac{|X|\cdot|Y|\cdot|Z|}{|X\cap Y|\cdot|XY\cap Z|}$$
   We can derive a similar formula if $(YZ)$ is a subgroup.
2. Many of the comments seem to suggest that such a formula probably do not exists. One of the reason cited is due to the fact that there isn’t a clear cut way for us to use induction because $XY$ is usually not a group.
3. Somebody (in an already deleted post) suggested the formula

$$|H_1H_2H_3|=\frac{|H_1||H_2||H_3|}{|H_1\cap H_2||H_2\cap H_3| |H_3\cap H_1|},$$

where $H_1,H_2,H_3$ are subgroups for $n=3$.

And in general,

$$|\displaystyle \prod_{i=l}^n(H_i)|=\frac{\displaystyle \prod_{i=l}^n(|H_i|)}{\displaystyle \prod_{i=l}^{n}(|H_i\cap H_{i+1}|)}$$

(Note that $H_{n+1}=H_1$)

where the ${H_i}’s$ are subgroups of $G$

It seemed plausible at first sight. Sadly, it too was quickly disproven using the same counter example for my conjectured formula. For the case of $n=3$, let the group $G$ be $S_3$, $H_1=\{(1),(12)\}$, $H_2=\{(1),(13)\}$ and $H_3=\{(1),(123),(132)\}$. In this example, it isn’t hard to see that the right hand side of the formula would give us $\frac{2\cdot 2\cdot 3}{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}=12$. However, on the left hand side of the formula, $XYZ$ is a subset of $S_3$ and hence its order has to be less than the cardinality of $S_3$ which is 6, a contradiction.

**My thoughts on this problem:**

I still think that there is a chance of there being such a formula. Clearly, one cannot simply work by induction on the number of factors because $XY$ is usually not a subgroup (as mentioned by Brauer Suzuki in the comments below). One approach that I can think of in solving this problem is to look at the proof for $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ and try to somehow replicate it for the case of $n=3$. (I have tried this but to no success. But feel free to try it because I am kind of new to algebra and hence might have missed something crucial)

At the same time, perhaps there is indeed no such formula. For arguments against such a formula do read the comments of ΑΘΩ below which I felt to be rather insightful.

**Conclusion:**

Pretty convinced that there isn’t such a formula. Do read the solution by David A. Craven.

Comment: The problem is that $XY$ is usually not a subgroup, so you cannot work by induction on the number of factors.

Comment: Just to give you an example. If $XY$ is a subgroup of group $G$,
then
$|XYZ|=|X|\cdot|Y|\cdot|Z|/(|X\cap Y|\cdot|XY\cap Z|)$.

Comment: When $G$ is Abelian (like in your first example), then all subgroups are normal, so $XY$ is a group and induction works.

Comment: @Explorer1234 May I begin by making a remark that might appear a mere hair-splitting matter at first sight but which actually hints to the reason why one shouldn't expect any generalisation to products of more than $2$ subgroups: given an arbitrary group $G$ and two subgroups $H, K  \leqslant G$ the product $HK$ no longer is a subgroup in general, therefore the syntagm *the order of $HK$* is not appropriate (one speaks of orders only in relation to groups, not to arbitrary sets). In the case of just two subgroups, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Explorer1234 *(cont.)* although their product is not necessarily a subgroup the result holds true by virtue of both factors in the product being subgroups. When extending to say three subgroups $K, H, F \leqslant G$ and forming the product $KHF$, the problem is that upon applying associativity and rewriting $KHF=K(HF)$, the product $HF$ no longer is a subgroup and therefore there is no way to implement an inductive reasoning. As one more remark, the relation in the result you reference is valid for *arbitrary* subgroups of *arbitrary* groups, with the form *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Perhaps this should be an answer (or put in an answer box) instead of a comment across several posts.  This would help in keeping it all together.

Comment: @Explorer1234 *(cont.)* $|KH|=|K||H \colon K \cap H|=|H||K \colon K \cap H|$.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki, kabenyuk and Mchael Burr Yeah I agree. If we were to assume that XY is a subgroup of G (somehow), then it isn’t very hard to deduce the formula of |XYZ| by induction.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Your thoughts on this matter is very thought provoking and insightful in my opinion. Especially the line “In the case of just ………  product being subgroups”. Your arguments seem to suggest that one should not expect a similar formula for |XYZ|. Then again, it is a rather intuitive argument and not a rigorous one so we certainly cannot rule out the possibility of there being such a formula. Perhaps if we were to write |XYZ| not only in terms of $|X|, |Y|, |Z|, |X\cap Y|, |X\cap Z|, |Y\cap Z|, |X\cap Y \cap Z|$ but also include terms such as $|XY|, |XZ|, |YZ|, |X\cap YZ|$,… Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has generated a lot of activity, so let's give an example to show that no formula can exist in general.

Let $G=GL_n(q)$, and let $B$ be the set of upper triangular matrices, of size $q^{n(n-1)/2}(q-1)^n$. Let $W$ denote the Weyl group of $GL_n(q)$, the symmetric group $S_n$, in its permutation representation. The Bruhat decomposition states that $$G=BWB.$$
This is exactly what you want, a triple subgroup decomposition. Since $B\cap W=1$ and $B\cap B=B$, intersections can be ignored. Since $BW$ is not a subgroup, and $BB=B$, we cannot use pairs of subgroups either. So we must make $|G|$, which is a product of many cyclotomic polynomials, out of $n!$, $1$ and $r=q^{n(n-1)/2}(q-1)^n$. Since the order of $G$ is a polynomial in $q$, and $n!$ does not depend on $q$, it can be treated as a constant for fixed $n$, hence ignored.

Thus we need to write $|G|=f(q)=q^{n(n-1)/2}\prod (q^i-1)$ as a polynomial $p(r)$, with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$. This is not possible. To see this, note that $|B|$ already divides $|G|$, so we need to write $|G|/|B|$ as a polynomial in $|B|$. Since $|B|$ has degree $n(n+1)/2$ and $|G|$ has degree $n^2-1$ (as polynomials in $q$), such a function cannot exist, as $n(n+1)/2$ does not divide $n^2-1$.

(To see why the polynomials must actually match, and they not just happen to coincide, since the formula must hold for infinitely many $q$, the polynomials must match as they have the same value infinitely often.)

Comment: Note that if any two of $XY$ and $YZ$ are subgroups then we can simply use the standard formula twice to obtain a formula for $XYZ$. This shows that there is no formula even for the case $XYX$ in general.

Comment: (If you want to use $BW$ as a subset rather than a subgroup, then $|BW|=n!r$, so of no use. Intersections with it yield the original subgroups back. If you want to use $\langle B,W\rangle$ instead, that yields $G$, so the formula wouldn't give us much.)

Comment: Impressive. Pretty convinced that there isn’t such a formula any more. Thanks!